# How to read a Future<File> path?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to display a Future path but I'am stalking with it, when I want to display this variable , they told me it's an instance of Future I don't know how to read it , could someone help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```dart
String _path = "";
_getPath() async {
   final file = await getFile(); // the method return Future<File>
   setState((){
     _path = file.path
   })
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `FutureBuilder` widget or use `async/await` or `then`

here are some resources that may help you :

https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ek8ZPdWj4Qo